# logback console display not honoring threshold filter

Tags: logback

I have a logback.xml file containing the following:

```
<appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="debugfile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender" >
    <file>debugFile.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>debugFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <MaxHistory>30</MaxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="infofile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender" >
    <file>infoFile.log</file>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>infoFile_%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <minIndex>1</minIndex>
        <maxIndex>3</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="warnfile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender" >
    <file>infoFile.log</file>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>WARN</level>
    </filter>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>warnFile_%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <minIndex>1</minIndex>
        <maxIndex>3</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!-- Setup the Root category -->
<root>
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    <appender-ref ref="debugfile"/>
    <appender-ref ref="infofile"/>
<appender-ref ref="warnfile"/>
</root>
```

I want it to only show me INFO level logs or greater.  So, I added the ThresholdFilter and set its level to INFO.  Doing this worked for the RollingFileAppender (where one includes INFO and greater and the other includes DEBUG and greater).

This didn't make a difference as the console statements continue to include DEBUG level statements.  Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: I used your  logback xml and  logback-classic:1.1.3. Works fine for me. Which version of logback you are using ?

Comment: 1.1.2 also logs only INFO level loggers and not DEBUG level loggers with your xml( on console). Either the loaded logback xml or  the loaded loggger implementation is not what you think is.

Comment: I have three applications, all similar and all using the same logback.xml file.  The filtering works on all three when writing to file, but only two of the three when writing to the console!?!?!?

Comment: Beware classloaders might persist old version of a recent configuration change when working within an IDE or SBT. you would need to exit IDE and restart again to see if it improves the outcome

Answer (score 0):

I can't guarentee that this will work, didn't actually test the setup.

Add  element after your .

```
<logger name="ch.qos.logback" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</logger>
```

That should modify the logging level of only the referenced appenders to the desired level.

See [Logback docs](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#loggerElement) for some more info on the thinking here.